# Conditional statement in where clause not working

Tags: sql

I want to show results according to distance for e.g. if distance is under 300 than results till 300. If it is not under 300 than only take second condition which is under 400.

But i am getting all results for e.g. 118,149,357

my inner select statement returns distance through a function

```
SELECT  A.Id, A.Distance FROM 
(
    SELECT  Id, ROUND((dbo.GetDistance(@Latitude, @Longitude, Latitude, Longitude)*1000),0) AS Distance 
    FROM Messages WITH (NOLOCK) where LEN(Latitude) > 0 AND LEN(Longitude) > 0


)  A 
WHERE 
    (A.Distance <= 300
      OR
      A.Distance <= 400)
ORDER BY Distance ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Id,
                Round(( dbo.Getdistance(@Latitude, @Longitude, Latitude, Longitude) * 1000 ), 0) AS Distance
         FROM   Messages WITH (NOLOCK)
         WHERE  Len(Latitude) > 0
                AND Len(Longitude) > 0)
SELECT A.Id,
       A.Distance
FROM   cte a
WHERE  A.Distance <= 300
        OR ( A.Distance <= 400
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM   cte B
                             WHERE  B.Distance <= 300) )
ORDER  BY Distance ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

A `WHERE` clause is evaluated for each row. Inside your filter for one specific row, you cannot use the existence of other rows in the same result set as a criterion in your filter.

You have to re-think your approach. One way I can think of is to rank the rows by distance, and select the top 1 rank:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT Id, ROUND((dbo.GetDistance(@Latitude, @Longitude, Latitude, Longitude)*1000),0) AS Distance 
  FROM Messages WITH (NOLOCK)
  WHERE LEN(Latitude) > 0 AND LEN(Longitude) > 0
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT Id, Distance, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Distance <= 300 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS [Rank]
  FROM cte1
  WHERE Distance <= 400
)
SELECT Id, Distance
FROM cte2
WHERE [Rank] = 1
ORDER BY Distance ASC
```

Disclaimer: untested, may have trivial errors, but the general approach should work.

Answer (score -1):

```
WHERE (A.Distance <= 300 OR A.Distance <= 400)
```

could be simplified to

```
WHERE A.Distance <= 400
```

because `300 <= 400` and therefore your result is correct.

Comment: This is both correct and useless, I think: it tells the OP what's wrong, but not even a hint on how to rewrite the condition to get the desired result.

Comment: The desired result is `A.Distance  <= 400`, obviously.

Comment: yes but.. i have look for 300 meters first.. and if i am getting results with 300 then i have to ignore 400 meters..

Comment: @Smutje The desired result is obviously not that. :) The OP already explained the desired result in the question before the comment here.

Comment: So, maybe you should run two separate queries - otherwise give us a concrete example and desired result.